# Custom Subscription Center

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've created a custom subscription center that pulls fields from a DE and then searches for the associated lists in regards to the subscriber who's on the profile center.

My question is how I make these lists work like publication lists, I want to be able to add people to these lists when I send from a UI?

Comment: Is your subscription center adding/removing subscribers on these lists? What data is in the DE? Would you mind updating your question with a bit more detail?

Comment: Yes it is adding/removing subscribers from the lists, the problem is when it comes to actually sending to emails. Normally through a UI you can add a publication list on top of a DE, but you can't add normal lists to the UI.

Comment: In regards to the DE I created the dE to host the fields I want to display on the profile center, which you can see in this code. http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_custom_profile_center_using_ampscript_and_the_soap_api/ @KellyJAndrews

Answer (score 0):

If you are properly updating list membership using the SubscriberList object (as demonstrated in the [code sample](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_custom_profile_center_using_ampscript_and_the_soap_api.htm) referenced in your comment), then the list is basically the same Publication List.

You can select Lists in UI Send Definitions.

[image]

Comment: Yup I am using that code sample, although that puts the users onto a normal list and not a publication list. If you try to move a DE over you will notice that a gray bar pops up under the heading "Targeted" on the right side. This essentially lets you use DE's while adding these people to the publication list.

Comment: Right.  Lists and Publication Lists are handled the same in the API -- they're both List Objects, so if you're primarily sending to DEs then you'll want to also  utilize Publication Lists to ensure Subscriber status is handled properly, especially Unsub Events.